# Usage of restrict on two pointers pointing to same array

Tags: c, pointers, restrict-qualifier

I'm having quite hard time making proper usage of `restrict` keyword in C. I wrote this function to in-place reverse a string:

```
void my_strrev(char *restrict str, const size_t len) {
    char *restrict strr = str + len - 1;
    char temp;
    while (str < strr) {
        temp = *str;
        *str++ = *strr;
        *strr-- = temp;
    }
}
```

Here, although both `str` and `strr` are pointing to same array, I'm using those pointers to access individual characters, and they never point to same characters. Hence I think this is a proper use of `restrict`. Also I got expected output when I run this program with few sample inputs. But I'm unsure of my usage of `restrict`. So, please correct me if I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I suggest to compare the assembly of two variants of this function - one with the restrict keyword and one without it. (use objdump).

Comment: @ArnonCharas There is no reason why `restrict` would give different machine code here though, so it doesn't sound very meaningful to compare the disassembly. I would be very surprised if there were any differences.

Comment: And to prove in practice that I'm right: https://godbolt.org/z/5nbEW495a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`restrict` has pretty much one single use - a contract that the programmer signs up with the compiler saying "I promise that I won't pass parameters pointing at the same data to this function with external linkage." This is still to this day mostly based on the compiler trusting the programmer, rather than the compiler giving diagnostic messages when the programmer "breaks the contract".

If the compiler can assume that the programmer kept their side of the bargain, it can make optimizations:

- It can assume that buffers passed to a function won't overlap - no need for temporary storage. (See `memcpy` vs `memmove` for example.)
- It can assume that different pointer parameters aren't aliases of each other, pointing to the same data. (Which could be possible if you have for example a `char*` and an `int*` parameter.)
- It can assume that pointer parameters aren't modifying any external linkage resources ("globals") used by the function, but that all access to what the pointer points at happens through that pointer.

Using `restrict` for a local pointer variable isn't very meaningful since it doesn't relate to any of the above situations. It will compile but there will be no benefits of using it. As far as I know, no additional diagnostics is currently provided by any of the mainstream compilers, should you use a `restrict` pointer inappropriately.

Comment: `restrict` in block scope may not be meaningful here. But if anyone want to see it's actual use case, can see one example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict#:~:text=.-,Block%20scope,-A%20block%20scope)

Comment: If I have a `char*` and an `int*` as argument to a function, is it required to use `restrict` for optimization? or can compiler infer `restrict`ness based on different datatype.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB `char*` can be a pointer alias of `int*` so it can't do that optimization. Had it been `double*` and `int*` it would be another story. This is all about the "strict aliasing rules".

Answer (score 1):

`restrict` essentially says that all the memory the function accesses through that pointer will not be accessed any other way, i.e., not also through another parameter or pointers loaded in any other way or via external objects.

It is okay to assign the parameter to other variables and to use those variables to access memory. Those accesses still derive from the original pointer. They are not derived from a different parameter or other source.

Comment: Should I use `restrict` in `struct`s having multiple pointers as members?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: That depends on what the pointers point to. `restrict` is used to tell the compiler that an object will be accessed only through the pointer marked `restrict` (unless the object is not modified by any means during execution of the applicable code). If a pointer points to data that may be shared through different pointers, it should not be marked `restrict`. If it points to data that “belongs” only to that pointer, it can be marked `restrict`. Whether it is useful or not depends on circumstances; `restrict` is intended to let the compiler optimize in certain cases.