# How to use C keyword restrict to decorate return pointer correctly?

Tags: python, c, restrict-qualifier

In some documents, I learned that we shall use 'restrict' to decorate function parameters or memory allocation statements. Like this:

```
    void(int*restrict paraA){}
    int*restrict A = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int);
```

And I'm confused about whether a 'restricted' pointer can be returned by any function.
Here I have a function funcA:

```
int* funcA(paraA, paraB){
    int*restrict result = (int*)calloc(10,sizeof(int));
    ......
    return result;
}
```

Could I just use the return pointer like this? Will it be safe?

```
void funcB(){
    int*restrict pA = funcA(0, 0);
    pA[0] = 1;
}
```

In msvc, I learn about `__declspec(restrict)`.
Should I use `__declspec(restrict) int* funcA()` or `int*restrict funcA()` instead in gcc?
And if I want to use funcA in Python, will `__declspec(dllexport,restrict) int* funcA()` effect the result in Python compared with `declspec(dllexport) int* funcA()`?

Comment: Just because of lack of time, here's simply [something to read](https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html).

Comment: The effect of `restrict` is limited to execution of the block it is used in, so the declaration of `int * restrict result` inside `funcA` affects only translation of `funcA`. It is not conveyed to the caller in any way. In `funcB`, presumably you have some other pointers in such a function, not shown in the code in the question. Then `restrict` would inform the compiler that memory accessed via `pA` does not overlap memory accessed via pointers with other origins. If that assertion is true, then the use of `restrict` is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage of `restrict` doesn't make much sense. The keyword only serves a purpose when you have two or more pointers to compatible types and the compiler can't know if they potentially point at the same object. Or if they possibly point to an object with external linkage ("global") in the same translation unit. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952974/584518).

In `funcA` the pointer has no relation to any other pointer or object in the program, since it is assigned to dynamic memory inside the function. `restrict` fills no obvious purpose at all in that function.

Comment: Given `void foo(size_t N, int *A, int *B)` where `A` and `B` might or might not point to overlapping memory and hence could not be `restrict` qualified, why would it not be useful to have some `int * restrict C = bar(N);` inside the function that used `restrict` to inform the compiler that `C` did not point to memory that overlaps `A` or `B`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not sure which question you are commenting about, but this answer is about the code posted here in this question...

Comment: Code has been elided or constructed for inquiry; the snippets shown are not samples of actual deployed code. OP is asking about using `restrict` in general, not just in the skeletal code shown.